# JavaScript - Trying to resize image size with mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and I'm trying to resize the image size by scrolling the mouse wheel. I run this in Chrome.

This code only resizes its height but not its width; I've tried working it out on paper by substituting numbers into img1.height and img1.width and it works but not when I run the code.

HTML

```
<img id="img1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_(Auto_Exposure).jpg" style="position:absolute; transition: 1s all">
```

JAVASCRIPT --- **wrong code, not working, only height changes**

```
function changeSize(e) {
    var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
    var slope = img1.height / img1.width;

    img1.height = img1.height + e.deltaY;
    img1.width = img1.height / slope;
}

function init() {
    window.onwheel = changeSize;
}

window.onload = init;
```

With the same HTML code, the code below works but I don't understand why copying the new height to a variable and using that variable instead of the image height works.

JAVASCRIPT --- **correct code, working, both height and width changes**

```
function changeSize(e) {
    var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
    var slope = img1.height / img1.width;
    var change = img1.height + e.deltaY;

    img1.height = change;
    img1.width = change / slope;
}

function init() {
  window.onwheel = changeSize;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Do not change height at all, resizing width will auto-resize height AND keeps aspect ratio

Comment: Is auto-resize height when resizing width a CSS thing? Or something entirely different?

Comment: Well, technically it's browser thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img1.height = img1.height + e.deltaY;
img1.width = img1.height / slope;
```

In this code above there is an attempt to assign a value to image height and to read it immediately. The problem is that image properties are set asynchronously. In order to read the height value, that is previously assigned, you should wait for an `onload` event, like this:

```
img1.height = img1.height + e.deltaY;
img1.onload = function() {
    img1.width = img1.height / slope;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation! :) Though there's a typo on the 2nd line of your 2nd code block. **img1**

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. Fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Specify only one dimension in the markup / css, and change that via the `wheel` event. Image will resize keeping the aspect ratio intact.

Try it in the snippet below:

```js
var image = document.getElementById('image');
image.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  this.width += Math.floor(e.deltaY);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
img { 
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="//placehold.it/240x120/33d/fff">
```

Comment: Very nice! Any idea how I would resize a div element that is on top of this image? I tried adding another addEventListener but does this just work for <img> elements?

Answer (score 0):

In this code **Non working**:

```
function changeSize(e) {
    var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
    var slope = img1.height / img1.width;

    img1.height = img1.height + e.deltaY;
    img1.width = img1.height / slope;
}

function init() {
    window.onwheel = changeSize;
}

window.onload = init;
```

If we add `alert` like this:

```js
function changeSize(e) {
    var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
    var slope = img1.height / img1.width;
    img1.height = img1.height + e.deltaY;
    alert(img1.height);
    img1.width = img1.height / slope;
}

function init() {
    window.onwheel = changeSize;
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_(Auto_Exposure).jpg" style="position:absolute; transition: 1s all">
```

Now we see that the code starts to work as expected.But the point to notice is that the value of alert is the previous image height not the updated one even it is written after `img1.height = img1.height + e.deltaY;`.Since the `img1.height` value does not update until the code ends this is happening.The alert box takes the focus away from the current window and when we close it again switches to current window thats why code works in case of `alert`

In this code **Working**:

```
function changeSize(e) {
    var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
    var slope = img1.height / img1.width;
    var change = img1.height + e.deltaY;

    img1.height = change;
    img1.width = change / slope;
}

function init() {
  window.onwheel = changeSize;
}

window.onload = init;
```

In this code `img1.height` as well as `img1.width` depends on a variable value `change`.Since the value of variable updates during the runtime of the function it changes the height and width of image.

Now the point to see is that:

```js
function changeSize(e) {
    var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
    var slope = img1.height / img1.width;
    var change = img1.height + e.deltaY;
    img1.height = change;
    alert(img1.height);
    img1.width = change / slope;
}
function init() {
  window.onwheel = changeSize;
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_(Auto_Exposure).jpg" style="position:absolute; transition: 1s all">
```

If we alert in this code also it shows the previous height of the image.

**Therefore I conclude that the height and width of the image changes after the end of the function and since in first code the width depends on updating the height so it does not changes**

Comment: I tested your alert in the non-working code block, it only worked the first time then it width stays the same afterward despite height changes. And I don't think the updates happen after the function end because I'm not returning anything.

Comment: It changes, which browser are you using

Comment: I'm using Chrome as stated in the beginning of my question.

Comment: In this answer i am trying to explain you why the two codes are behaving differently not trying to give you a solution since the best solution is using the second code.